# WCF 4 Routing service wif

Tags: wcf, routes, wif

Does anybody know would be the configuration of the routing service for one scenario like the one described here http://zamd.net/2011/02/08/silverlight-claim-based-security/?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not complete since I have not fully tested yet. However the following link seems interesting : [WCF4 routing with WIF](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-MY/Geneva/thread/d7c25415-17a9-4786-9f28-2ba8deb14a96)

Also [this](http://zamd.net/2011/03/23/silverlight-claim-based-security-part-2/)